# Open application using python on Mac

Tags: python, macos, subprocess

So I need to be able to open applications through a python script that runs based off of user input. (i.e. if someone types 'Word' the program opens Microsoft Word)

So what is the proper context using subprocess.Popen() to open an application like Word or MySqlWorkbench or something? any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This should help get you started:

```
import subprocess

def get_app_name(appNamesList, app):
    for appName in appNamesList:
        if app in appName:
            return appName
    return ""


p = subprocess.Popen(["ls",  "/Applications/"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
appNames = p.communicate()[0].split("\n")

appNameEntered = raw_input('What app would you like to open?')

appName = get_app_name(appNames, appNameEntered)

if appName != "":
    p = subprocess.Popen(["open", "-n", "/Applications/" + appName], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
else:
    print 'No app with that name installed'
```

Example input: `Photo B`, which should open `Photo Booth.app`